# PyTorch - unable to use batchnorm1d with Linear

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization

Using PyTorch's `BatchNorm1D` on a 1-D tensor gives the error:

> RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 1 elements not 2304

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

**My Code:**

```
self.net_common = nn.Sequential (
    nn.Linear(64*64, 48*48),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(48*48),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
    nn.Linear(48*48, 32*32),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(32*32),
    nn.Tanh(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2D tensor as input, since `BatchNorm1d` works with mini-batches:

> Applies Batch Normalization over a 2D or 3D input (a mini-batch of 1D inputs with optional additional channel dimension)...
>   [More](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#batchnorm1d)

You can try `torch.unsqueeze` to fix your input dimensions. [More](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze)

Answer (score 0):

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm1d

the explain of Parameters

**num_features** – C from an expected input of size (N, C, L) or L from input of size (N, L)
I think the C means the channel and the L means Length of data, N means the batch size. so if you input shape is (N, C, L), maybe C is 1 or 3, you can use

```py
···
nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
···
```

For test, you can use the code below:

```py
m = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
d = torch.randn(4, 1, 8)
output = m(d)
```